# How can I change the shape of this numpy array to (3058, 480, 640, 3)?

Tags: image, numpy, resize, reshape, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to read 3058 images from a folder. I want my picture to be read as np array with size (3158, 480, 640, 3) dtype as uint8. I store all image to a list (image_list). After changing the list to array, I get an array (3158, ). Below is my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

DIR = mydir
takenFrames = 6
counter = 0

 for filename in glob.glob(DIR + '/*.png'):

                            counter += 1
                            # if counter >= no frames, open image, add img and img_label to list.
                            if (counter >= takenFrames):

                                im = cv.imread(filename) #im.shape is 480, 640
                                image_list.append(im)                   

                                #im = np.resize(im, (-1, 490, 640, 3))


image_list = np.array(image_list, dtype='uint8').reshape(-1, 480, 640, 3) / 255.0
```

Whenever I try to do this, I get the following error as below

image_list = np.array(image_list, dtype='uint8').reshape(-1, 480, 640, 3) / 255.0
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    image_list = np.array(image_list, dtype='uint8').reshape(-1, 480, 640, 3) / 255.0

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I tried accessing an image from a single folder and the below line of code works
x = np.array([np.array(Image.open(file)) for file in filename]) #x.shape = (55, 480, 640, 3)

I tried to store x in an empty numpy array whenever I access a different folder and read the images to get all the 3058 images as

```
data = np.array([])

            #I tried to append numpy array as
                                if(data.size == 0):
                                    data = im

                                else:   
                                    data = np.append(data, im, axis = 0)
```

but that doesn't work either

Comment: What's the `dtype` of this 1d array?  Probably `object`.  Combining arrays that differ in shape produces this kind of array.  With images the problem can be size, or a mix of 3 channel and 1 channel images.

Comment: Yes, the dtype of the 1d array is object. So do you have any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: `np.append` is not a valid substitute for list append.

Comment: I just figured this out. Some of the images have different shape that is the reason. I solved it by changing the image shape before appending the list.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out. Some of the images have different shape that is the reason. I solved it by changing the image shape before appending the list.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

DIR = mydir
takenFrames = 6
counter = 0

for filename in glob.glob(DIR + '/*.png'):

                            counter += 1
                            # if counter >= no frames, open image, add img and img label to list.
                            if (counter >= takenFrames):

                                im = cv.imread(filename)

#some images are of size (480, 640, 3) whereas some are (490, 640, 3). I resized all images to (480, 640, 3)          

                                im = np.resize(im, (480, 640, 3))

                                image_list.append(im)
                                labels.append(label)

#converting image_list to numpy array changes my list to (3058, 480, 640, 3)

import numpy as np
image_list = np.asarray(image_list)
```